# Neo4j: How to satisfy first seen sender + first seen attachment to multiple recipients

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with inbound email data.  The goal of this specific cypher query is to return when there is a `first seen sender and first seen attachment sent to multiple recipients`.

The `attachment` looks like the following:

```
<id>:16107  containsMultipleExtensions:nofileExtension:jpg  firstseen:"2020-01-14T06:12:09Z" lastseen:"2020-01-14T06:12:09Z" name:090aa40109043fc6383ba8498e22b5338af8c8ddec0ea2  timesseen:12
```

The `sender` looks like the following:

```
<id>:13329  domain:example.com  firstseen:"2020-01-14T06:12:09Z" lastseen:"2020-01-14T06:12:09Z"  name:sales@example.com  timesseen:48
```

To get the first seen sender and recipient I would select only when `s.firstseen = s.lastseen AND a.firstseen = a.lastseen`.  That way I would only be selecting when it was the first time either was seen.

But I am having issues with the path portion.  I am looking for when 1 sender(first time) sends 1 or more attachments(first time) to more than one recipients.

This is what I have so far.

```
MATCH path = (s:Sender)-->(a:Attachment)-->(:Recipient)
WHERE s.firstseen = s.lastseen AND a.firstseen = a.lastseen
WITH s, COUNT(DISTINCT a) AS cnt, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE cnt >= 2
RETURN paths
```

Which returns:
[image]

This seems to do what I want it to except for it includes single recipients(like the example on the left.  How can I fix this so it only displays when a sender sends emails only like the results on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your condition is on `cnt` which is counting the number of attachments. In the left subgraph in the picture above, you can see one sender sending multiple attachments to one recipient. So if you are "looking for when 1 sender(first time) sends 1 or more attachments(first time) to more than one recipients", move your condition to the count of `Recipient`:

```
MATCH path = (s:Sender)-->(a:Attachment)-->(r:Recipient)
WHERE s.firstseen = s.lastseen AND a.firstseen = a.lastseen
WITH s, COUNT(distinct r) as cnt, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE cnt >= 2
RETURN paths
```